# Multiple select queries in a single mysql table

Tags: mysql

I'm still learning PHP and MySql by writing simple programs. In my latest project I face a problem which you may find very simple but I'm stuck.

I have a table like this:

```
id |  text       |  create_date         | active | featured | featured_end
---+-------------+----------------------+--------+----------+--------------------
1  |Some text 1  |  2016-02-10 17:32:51 | 1      | 0        | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
2  |Some text 2  |  2016-02-09 17:32:51 | 1      | 1        | 2016-03-05 17:32:51
3  |Some text 3  |  2016-02-08 17:32:51 | 1      | 1        | 2016-03-05 17:32:51
4  |Some text 4  |  2016-02-07 17:32:51 | 0      | 0        | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
5  |Some text 5  |  2016-02-06 17:32:51 | 1      | 0        | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
6  |Some text 6  |  2016-02-05 17:32:51 | 1      | 0        | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
7  |Some text 7  |  2016-02-04 17:32:51 | 1      | 1        | 2016-03-05 17:32:51
8  |Some text 8  |  2016-02-03 17:32:51 | 1      | 0        | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
9  |Some text 9  |  2016-02-02 17:32:51 | 0      | 0        | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
10 |Some text 10 |  2016-02-01 17:32:51 | 1      | 1        | 2016-03-05 17:32:51
```

I need to get all the results from this table with some filters:

1) The result must include only active  = 1

2) featured = 1 must be in the beginning of the result set

3) AND if featured = 1 THEN featured_end must be greater than now()

I tried this(doesn't work):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `active` = 1 
UNION SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `featured` = 1
HAVING `featured_end` > now()
ORDER BY `featured` 
DESC, `create_date` DESC
```

This one doesn't work either:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `active` = 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `featured` = 1 AND `featured_end` > NOW())
) table
ORDER BY `featured` DESC
```

Obviously, I'm missing something or I am completely on a wrong path. Can you please direct me to the correct path?

Comment: Have a good look at your errors and try to figure out what they mean. Mysql does a nice job at locating where the error is.

Comment: Actually, I am not getting any SQL errors with the queries but at the same time I can not get the results that I need.

Comment: Ok, but I already see people did your homework anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it should do the job.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `active` = 1
AND (
    (`featured` = 1 AND `featured_end` > now())
    OR `featured` = 0
)
ORDER BY `featured` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me and I learned a new way of doing things in SQL

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use sub-queries based the last query you've posted. Your query is fairly close (to that solution), but it requires some small changes.

Since each row has an unique `id`, you can use easily use sub-queries that select ID's to add to the result.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `active` = 1 OR
      `id` IN (
           SELECT `id`
           FROM `table`
           WHERE `featured` = 1 AND
                 `featured_end` > NOW()
      )
ORDER BY `featured` DESC
```

As you can see, you select the `id` fields in the sub-query. Then you include the selected rows in the main query using `id IN(...)` with the `WHERE` clause. It's important for performance reasons that you only select the `id` fields in the sub-query, the other fields are omitted and will be included anyways by the main `SELECT` query.

It does however, look like it's also possible to use this strategy (defining your whole `WHERE` clause in a single query):

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `active` = 1 AND ((
              `featured` = 1 AND
              `featured_end` > now()
          ) OR `featured` = 0
      )
ORDER BY
    `featured` DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations and examples. You helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE active = 1 AND ((CASE WHEN featured = 1 THEN featured_end ELSE NOW()) >= NOW())
ORDER BY featured DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a single query or a pair of unioned queries. Single query looks simpler, but requires an OR in the WHERe that would limit the use of indexes.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `active` = 1 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `featured` = 1
AND `featured_end` > now()
ORDER BY `featured` DESC, 
        `create_date` DESC
```